# Python: how to associate a probability to a given value?

Tags: python, probability

I would like to associate a probability value to a number.

Let's say, I consider a norman probability distribution with `mean = 7` and `std = 3`.

I can generate a random number based on such distribution in this way

```
np.random.normal(7, 3, 1)
```

I would like to find a method to associate to a given number the value of the probability associated to it.

For instance, what is the value of the probability associated with 0.6 based on such distribution?

Let's assume I generate the histogram of `n` random values.

```
x = np.random.normal(7, 3, 100000)
plt.hist(x, 10)
```

[image]

Here I can I see that a value of `5` has a probability of `~0.11` while a value of `20` has probability `0`.

Comment: for Normal distribution, the probability of a particular value is 0, you can only assign probability to a range of values.

Comment: @ilyankou Not just for a normal distribution but for *any* continuous distribution.

Comment: yes yes–was just answering this particular question.

Comment: I could retrieve the valued from the cdf, no?

Comment: yes but for stuff like P(x<0.6)

Comment: @emax The CDF doesn’t give you the point probability of a value. It gives you the probability of a random variable being less than or equal to a value.

Comment: A histogram doesn’t show you the probability of values either. It shows you the size of arbitrarily defined *bins* (i.e. intervals). If you change the binning, the “probability” changes). Try `plt.hist(x, 11)` and you’ll see that the height of the bin containing 5 will have  a drastically different height).

Comment: FYI your histogram above is not normalized and the probabilities don't add to 1.  The probabilities you're quoting are not correct and off by a factor of ~2 too low

Answer (score 0):

For any normalized continuous distribution represented on a histogram as you have above, the only way to find the probability for a given histogram bin is to take the integral of that distribution over the range of the bins.  So this depends on:

1. The distribution
2. The range of the bin you are considering

You can use the scipy package for example to do this integral numerically for you.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

If you need something more simple, you can approximate this probability by taking the value of the CDF at the center of the bin and multiplying by the width of the bin.